# UIscrollview derived classes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, derived

Which are the controls (or classes) derived from UIScrollView?

Comment: Oh, and your markup sucked a little. Please indent **only code** with at least 4 spaces. DO NOT INDENT TEXT!! Thank you. For more information about formatting, you can go here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Koning, was there really any need to shout? Also, if you're answering the question, why post it as a comment? Why not an answer? :)

Comment: @Jasarien: Shout? Well, actually not meant as such, the exclamations are more like for importance.

And 'Why not answer?': good question xD

Answer (score 2):

You can find the UIKit class hierarchy here: [UIKit Graph Hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Art/uikit_classes.jpg)

(more information here: [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html))